# How can I explode a large Array into multiple columns in Hive

Tags: hive

I have the following table:

```
ID  Data
101 [0,0,1,1,1]
102 [0,0,0,1,0]
103 [1,0,1,0,1]
```

How do I explode the array into multiple columns without using Array index (because the actual Array has ~16k elements) to produce the following table:

```
ID   Data_1  Data_2  Data_3  Data_4  Data_5
101  0       0       1       1       1
102  0       0       0       1       0
101  1       0       1       0       1
```

I can't just do:

```
SELECT ID, Data[0], Data[1], Data[2], Data[3], Data[4] FROM tmp_table;
```

because I have around 16,000 elements in the array and that will end up being quite a large query.

EDIT: I need to do this using Hiveql so can't use PySpark.

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark, you can aggregate the dataframe to calculate the size of the max array in the column `Data` then dynamically extract the array items based on the position inside array

```
size = df.agg(F.max(F.size('Data'))).first()[0]
df1 = df.select('ID', *[F.col('Data')[i].alias(f'Data_{i + 1}') for i in range(size)])
```

---

```
+---+------+------+------+------+------+
| ID|Data_1|Data_2|Data_3|Data_4|Data_5|
+---+------+------+------+------+------+
|101|     0|     0|     1|     1|     1|
|102|     0|     0|     0|     1|     0|
+---+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned that I know how to do this in Spark/Pyspark. I need to figure out how to do it in Hive using Hiveql